# Is it possible to override SwiftUI modifiers?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Knowing that with SwiftUI view modifiers, order matters - because each modifier is a part of a chain of modifiers, I was wondering if it was possible to reset/overwrite/override a modifier (or the whole chain?

Specifically, I'm wondering about Styles (`groupBoxStyle`, `buttonStyle`, etc). I have default styles that I want to use in 90% of my app, and a few pages will have slightly different styles for those widgets.

For example:

```swift
// Renders a button with the "light" style
Button("Hello world") {
}
.buttonStyle(LightButtonStyle())
.buttonStyle(DarkButtonStyle())

// Renders a button with the "dark" style
Button("Hello world") {
}
.buttonStyle(DarkButtonStyle())
.buttonStyle(LightButtonStyle())
```

In those cases, I would actually like the 2nd modifier to be used, but the 1st takes over and subsequent styles don't work.

Note: In my actual app, none of my use cases are this trivial - this is just the simplest proof of concept.

The workaround(s) I have are that I create separate `LightButton` and `DarkButton` views, but that feels very inelegant (and becomes a mess when I have 5-6 variants of each component).

Alternatively, I have a custom `MyButton(myStyle: ButtonStyle = .myDefaultStyle)`, but since this is a forms app, there are about 50-60 locations where something like that needs to be updated (instead of applying a modifier at a top level and letting that cascade through).

Edit: I should note, where I can set a top-level style and let it cascade, that works very well and as expected (closer to the View, the modifier takes over). But, there are just some weird use cases where it would be nice to flip the script.

Comment: You can create your own modifiers, see for instance here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/custom-modifiers

Comment: Sure, but within those custom modifiers, I don't think I'm able to override previous modifiers. That's kinda the crux of the question. I know there are many workarounds, but I just don't know about overriding.

Comment: You can’t override, the inner modifier takes precedence, that is a natural flow since you normally provide more vague modifiers above but if you put a modifier inside it is because you want that behavior.

Comment: If you consider the actual relationship between things, you will see that "convenience of cascading" is not expressible with any non-ambiguous rule. I.e. most of the times you will want to add modifiers to existing ones, and in a few times you will want to override them. How would SwiftUI know which is which?
So I think either having custom views (5-6 of them is actually not that many, especially since they can mostly share the code), or having to supply a style (except for a default) in modifier is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `buttonStyle` propagates to child views, so ideally you would only need to set your “house style” once on the root view of your app.

The well-known place where this fails to work is the presentation modifiers like  `.sheet`, which do not propagate styles to the presented view hierarchy. So you will need to write your own versions of the presentation modifiers that re-apply your house style.

For example, here's a custom `ButtonStyle`:

```
struct HouseButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(20)
            .background {
                Capsule(style: .continuous)
                    .foregroundColor(.pink)
            }
            .saturation(configuration.isPressed ? 1 : 0.5)
    }
}
```

And here's a cover for `sheet` that applies the custom button style to the presented content:

```
extension View {
    func houseSheet<Content: View>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) -> some View {
        return sheet(isPresented: isPresented, onDismiss: onDismiss) {
            content()
                .buttonStyle(HouseButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

We can test out whether a `NavigationLink`, a `sheet`, and a `houseSheet` propagate the button style:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingHouseSheet = false
    @State var showingStandardSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Navigation Push") {
                    ContentView()
                }

                Button("Standard Sheet") {
                    showingStandardSheet = true
                }

                Button("House Sheet") {
                    showingHouseSheet = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingStandardSheet) {
                ContentView()
            }
            .houseSheet(isPresented: $showingHouseSheet) {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the root view that applies the house button style at the highest level:

```
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ContentView()
            .buttonStyle(HouseButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

If you play with this, you'll find that both `NavigationLink` and `houseSheet` propagate the button style to the presented content, but `sheet` does not.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was some magical solution I hadn't found, but I had low hopes of that :) I'll continue doing what I've been doing - but thanks for the extra ideas in your answer. I appreciate it!